# Add a "Save" action in local task to a node

Tags: nodes

I would like to add a new action to local task on node.
This new action has to save the current node.

I have drupal 8.8.0

I know how to add a new action.

But my question is about how to save the current edit node from it if it's possible.

My goal is to replace the "save" button at the bottom of the node on edit mode

Comment: "Save" is a form submit button, while local tasks are plain links outside the form. I don't think this is possible in a really reliable way (I believe an outside link with a JS form submit trigger is not reliable due e.g. form states API or Ajax bindings)

Answer (score 1):

Local tasks are the wrong tool for the job. [Local tasks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks) are for providing context-sensitive action links (e.g. Edit, Delete, View) around an item (e.g. node/user). Trying to make a local task become a form submission button would involve all kinds of hacks that probably would be more trouble than its worth.

If the goal is to alter the save button's position for UI concerns, look at using [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.8.x) to alter the appearance/positioning of the node form's **Save** button. For example, look at a module like [Floating Action Buttons](https://www.drupal.org/project/floating_action_buttons') that uses a form alter to place the action buttons in a fixed location.